# Plotting a dot that moves along side a dispersive wave?

Tags: python-3.x

How would I go on about plotting a dot that moves along a wave pack/superposition. I saw this on the website and wanted to try for myself.https://blog.soton.ac.uk/soundwaves/further-concepts/2-dispersive-waves/. So I know how to animate a superpositon of two sine waves. But how would I plot a dot that moves along it? I won't post my entire code, but it looks somewhat like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
N = 1000
x = np.linspace(0,100,N)

wave1 = np.sin(2*x)
wave2 = np.sin(3*x)
sWave = wave1+wave2

plt.plot(x,sWave)

plt.ion()

for t in np.arange(0,400):
    sWave.set_ydata(sWave)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(.1)

plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

Note that this is just a quick draft of my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `scatter` and update its data in a loop by using `.set_offsets()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 1000
x = np.linspace(0, 100, N)
wave1 = np.sin(2*x)
wave2 = np.sin(3*x)
sWave = wave1 + wave2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, sWave)
scatter = ax.scatter([], [], facecolor="red") # Initialize an empty scatter.

for t in range(N):
    scatter.set_offsets((x[t], sWave[t])) # Modify that scatter's data.
    fig.canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(.001)
```